# Django Admin - Filtering the filters

Tags: python, django, filter, django-admin

I got a quick question.

I currently have 2 models, tournaments and matches. Tournament has a One to Many relationship with Match.

Tournament has a field season.

Right, I am filtering Match by Tournament but as you guys might of guessed, there can be more than 1 season.

I would like to know how I can make it so that the user can filter by season and depending on the season he picks, the Tournament filter changes to get all tournaments in that season...

EDIT:

I see that there is some confusion, so let me explain a bit more.
I meant the list filters.

The one that you add like this:
list_filter = ['tournament_*season', 'tournament', 'category', 'tournament*_gender']

So basically what I want is, when someone chooses a tournament_*season, I want tournament to be filtered and show only the tournament from the chosen tournament*_season...

Thanks,
Ara

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear as to what this has to do with django-admin. If this doesn't do what you need please modify your question.

With regard to just generic django, this would be a matter of writing some code that does the filter you have just described. For instance you can get a list of all tournaments in a given season by doing:

```
tournaments = Tournament.objects.filter(season=season)
# Use tournaments as you usually would Tournament.objects
```

Comment: Hey, I think my question is indeed unclear. I edited it show what I mean!